# disable animation in BrowseFragment when selected item change

Tags: android-tv

I want to disable the default animation on items in a `BrowseFragment` when they are selected ie scaling animation and the change of position. I want the items to stay where they are and not change their size when selected.

So far I tried various things on my `ListRowPresenter` object like setting the `OnItemViewSelectedListene` to null but without successful effect.

How can I achieve this ? (I'm using the version 26 of the leanback library)

Answer (score 1):

You can set the zoom factor for the animation to none by passing in `ZOOM_FACTOR_NONE` to the constructor of the ListRowPresenter.

There is a constructor for ListRowPresenter to control the animation (focusZoom).

From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v17/leanback/widget/ListRowPresenter.html#ListRowPresenter(int)):

ListRowPresenter (int focusZoomFactor)

Constructs a ListRowPresenter with the given parameters.

Parameters

focusZoomFactor int: Controls the zoom factor used when an item view is focused. One of ZOOM_FACTOR_NONE, ZOOM_FACTOR_SMALL, ZOOM_FACTOR_XSMALL, ZOOM_FACTOR_MEDIUM, ZOOM_FACTOR_LARGE Dimming on focus defaults to disabled.

Example:

```
ArrayObjectAdapter adapter = 
        new ArrayObjectAdapter(new ListRowPresenter(ZOOM_FACTOR_NONE));
setAdapter(adapter);

ArrayObjectAdapter rowAdapter =
        new ArrayObjectAdapter(new MyCardViewPresenter(getContext()));

HeaderItem header = new HeaderItem("Header Title");
ListRow row = new ListRow(header, rowAdapter);

for (Video video : videos) {
     rowAdapter.add(video);
}
adapter.add(row);
```

Comment: I tried this without any effect. I'm implementing `PageRow` design, maybe it has some side effect ?

Comment: If I use this inside a `PageRow` the animation is actually disabled while selecting cards in the row. So this works but not on what I want. I need the menu animation to be disabled